# Forcing a JSONP call to convert text response to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

If I've got the following request

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: "callback",
    jsonpCallback: "my_callback",
    url: my_https_url,
    headers:{"Content-Type":"text/html; charset=utf-8"},
    success: function(data) {
        eval("json="+data);
    }
    error: function() {
        console.log("fail");
    }

});
```

I'm getting a server response with the 200 status code. The response header says it is sending back text/html as the content-type. However, I know the content is actually formatted JSON data. The problem is the server is not configured to accept JSONP requests (and I can't change it). I am using the JSONP approach for cross-domain-related reasons. The error status I get back is a "parseerror" because it's not recognized as JSON. Is there a way to override the function responsible for parsing the data so that I can force it to be treated as JSON? Possibly using eval()?

Comment: just use text and JSON.parse(theResponseText)

Comment: If it's not accepting JSONP requests, why do you try to use this approach then?!

Comment: I forgot one thing in the post (updated). I did change the the headers section to consider text. Still having problems.

Comment: @JoshBradley: The `headers` object specifies those that are sent with the *request*. Since a GET request does not have any content, setting the content-type is completely pointless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your server is not capable of creating a JSONP formatted response and you have to use JSONP because of same-origin restrictions, then you're just plain out of luck.  A JSONP formatted response is in the form of a executable script that calls the specified callback.

You generally can't fetch JSON from a different origin.  You either need JSONP or you need a modern browser with a server configured to allow cross origin requests.  If you can't configure the server to allow cross origin requests, then you need the server to create JSONP.  If it won't do that, then you can't get the data from it.  JSONP is a work-around for cross-origin requests and it REQUIRES server cooperation to create a JSONP formatted structure for the response.

---

If you are getting JSONP structure from the server and jQuery is getting a parse error when trying to parse the response as JSON, then that's because whatever the server is sending is not legal JSON inside of the JSONP structure.  The fact that you're getting a parse error would mean that jQuery is trying to parse it as JSON and is getting an error when trying to do so.  If that's the case, then you have two choices:

1. Fix the data the server is sending to be 100% legal JSON.
2. Accept the data as text and fix it to be legal JSON or parse it yourself in some manner that accepts it the way it is.

In either case, the first step is probably to `console.log()` the text that is being sent and understand exactly why it's not being accepted as legal JSON.  Then, you'll better know what your options are.  If you want help with understanding that, then add the exact server response to your question.

Comment: No, the parseerror is coming from jQuery trying to include JSON as a JSONP script.

Comment: @Bergi - I don't think we can tell exactly which reason is causing the parseError, but I've added info about that possible cause to my answer also.

Comment: how do you go about #2? the parsing seems to occur before the callback

Comment: @Fakeer - You'd have to have JSONP that was passing unparsed JSON to the callback and then configure your framework NOT to automatically try to parse it so you can get access to the raw JSON.

Comment: thanks. in my case it's just angular 1.6 $http.jsonp